# Howto access a service in a docker container from VM?

Tags: docker, networking

I have an Ubuntu host with a web app running inside a docker container.
The web app is accessible from Ubuntu PC via 172.19.0.XXX:8080.

Now I want to test how web app looks like in IE. For that I started VirtualBox with Win7.

How could I call web app from VM?

Already tried different VM network variants, such as default NAT with port forwarding; and bridge - without any luck

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the ports between the docker container and the Ubuntu host when starting the container by using `-p 8080:8080`, then you should be able to connect from Ubuntu using `localhost:8080`

Once you do that, find the IP address of the Ubuntu host by running `ifconfig` and use that IP to connect from the Windows VM via `http://<Ubuntu-ip>:8080`